# Why does my findOne query hang indefinitely?

Tags: strapi

I just created a [new project [GitHub]](https://github.com/whoisteri/question-strapi-fetchone-hangs) with `yarn create strapi-app` to test model lifecycle methods. I'm making a write-once read-many field called `number_of_onsite_lessons`. 
I want to have a field where a user can specify how many Onsine Lessons should be generated when creating an Onsite Course and then disable that field - or at least throw an error when they try to change its value.

To this end, I wrote a lifecycle method of OnsiteCourse:

```js
  // Before updating a value.
  // Fired before an `update` query.
  beforeUpdate: async (model, attrs, options) => {
    const prev = await strapi.query("onsite-course").findOne({_id: model.id});
    console.log(prev,model);

    if (prev.number_of_onsite_lessons != model.number_of_onsite_lessons) {
      throw new Error("Can't change number of lessons - delete or create onsite lessons instead.")
    }
    if (prev.number_of_onsite_projects != model.number_of_onsite_projects) {
      throw new Error("Can't change number of projects - delete or create onsite projects instead.")
    }
  },
```

When I update an OnsiteCourse entity, the code runs, but it stops at `await strapi.query("onsite-course").findOne({...})` and then hangs indefinitely. I don't get an error, nor do I get that console.log on the next line.

After a while, this error shows up in the console:

```
[2020-03-17T07:42:30.558Z] error TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Bluebird.try.then.catch (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:318:17)
    at tryCatcher (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at /home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/catch_filter.js:17:41
    at tryCatcher (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/teri/projects/strapi/new/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:443:21)
```

Comment: Can you please share your `onsite-course` content type.

Comment: @JimLAURIE I linked the git repository containing everything in the question. You can also find it here: https://github.com/whoisteri/question-strapi-fetchone-hangs

Comment: OKay can you please try to use camelCase Content Types, I think this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issues using `sqlite` connector (with `3.0.0-beta.20`)

```js
// tryed on beforeCreate, beforeUpdate and beforeSave
await strapi.query("product").findOne({ id: 1 })
await strapi.api.product.services.product.findOne({ id: 1 })
await strapi.api.product.controllers.product.findOne({ params: { id: 1 } })
await strapi.services.product.findOne({ id: 1 })
```

solved by using `mongodb` *(`mysql` and others should work too !)*